# python script for monkeyrunner with whitesprace on device.type method

Tags: python, scripting, monkeyrunner

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    device.touch(240, 740)
    device.type('5551234')
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(3)
```

this works great
The problem is when I have some white space like this:

```
device.type('55 5 12 34')
```

only '55' is printed

How can I print white space chars ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out what [this guy](http://distributedreasoner.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-monkeyrunner-and-google-adb.html) says:

> The first problem with MonkeyRunner for me came in the form of the
>   type function being broken when the space key is used. This is not
>   unique to Monkeyrunner. It appears that adb shell input text suffers
>   from a similar problem. There may be several other KeyEvents (other
>   than spaces) that fall into this particular hazard, but I was able to
>   get around the issue for now by removing spaces from the text to be
>   sent and inserting KEYCODE_SPACE where appropriate.

Comment: I am in 2017 and close to 2018 and still monkeyrunner suffers from spaces! Thank you @synthesizerpatel you have saved me sometime :)

Answer (score 8):

```
    for z in my_text.split(' '):
        device.type(z)
        device.press('KEYCODE_SPACE', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

this is the workaround I am using